# How to add or edit data in an array with data-linking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender, jsviews

A "working" copy of what I'm trying to do is below, I simply want to be able to add or edit data in the array but I have to do things like `$('#examQuestion').val()`.

That seems more like a hack.

I assume there is an easy solution to this with data-linking, I'm just not sure how to fix this.

Here is the [**code in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9WF6/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main"></div>

<script id="newTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Questoin Type</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea placeholder="Exam Question" rows="10" id="examQuestion" name="examQuestion" cols="50"></textarea>
        </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="examQuestionType" name="examQuestionType"><option value="0" selected="selected">-- Please select question type --</option><option value="1">Radio Button</option><option value="2">Checkbox</option><option value="3">Textarea</option><option value="4">Text</option></select>
        </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="addOrUpdateQuestion" type="button">Add / update</button>
        </td>
            </tr>
            {^{for questions}}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{:question}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{:typeName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="editQuestion" type="button">Edit</button>
          </td>
                </tr>
            {{/for}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jsviews.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var question = [];

      var app = {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        selectedQuestionId: -1,
        questions: question
      };

      var tmpl = $.templates("#newTmpl");
      tmpl.link("#main", app);

      $('#main').on('click', '.editQuestion', function() {
        var tmpData = $.view(this).data
        app.selectedQuestionId = $.view(this).index;
        $('#examQuestion').val(tmpData.question);
        $('#examQuestionType').val(tmpData.type);
      });

      $('#main').on('click', '.addOrUpdateQuestion', function() {
        if (app.selectedQuestionId == -1) {
          $.observable(question).insert({
            question: $('#examQuestion').val(),
            type: $('#examQuestionType').val(),
            typeName: $('#examQuestionType').find(':selected').text()
          });
        } else {
          var tmpItem = app.questions[app.selectedQuestionId];
          tmpItem.question = $('#examQuestion').val();
          tmpItem.type = $('#examQuestionType').val();
          tmpItem.typeName = $('#examQuestionType').find(':selected').text();
          app.questions[app.selectedQuestionId] = tmpItem;
          $.observable(question).refresh(question);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I look at this, it looks like its ripe for doing something with http://knockoutjs.com/, where the UI automatically reflects changes to the model (or another MVC framework)

Comment: Could you give me a jsFiddle example of what I'm trying to do, but with knockoutjs? I'm willing to use whatever works.

Comment: I was able to get a working example in KnockoutJs... http://jsfiddle.net/534R6/1/

Comment: nice, I just didn't have time to create an example like I wanted to... what do you think about using knockout for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well clearly JsViews is all about having UI automatically update when the model changes! Only the model can be the original data - raw object graph from a JSON request, for example, and does not have to be mapped to specific MVVM classes using specific types. (Responding here to the comments above on using Knockout - which does require specific wrappers). That said, JsViews also works very well with MVVM wrappers.

So here is a modified version of your example http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/F9WF6/3/

Important to note: all the data-linking using data-link attributes or `{^{...` - which was missing in your example.

BTW this: `data-link="selectedQuestion^type"` is an example of deep linking, so it updates both when the selectedQuestion switches to another one, and when the type property of the current selectedQuestion changes. For more on this see http://www.jsviews.com/#observe - talking about *leaf changes or deep changes*.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <textarea data-link="selectedQuestion^question" placeholder="Exam Question" rows="10" name="examQuestion" cols="20"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select data-link="selectedQuestion^type" name="examQuestionType">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please select question type --</option>
      <option value="1">Radio Button</option>
      <option value="2">Checkbox</option><option value="3">Textarea</option>
      <option value="4">Text</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button data-link="disabled{:selectedQuestion !== newQuestion || !selectedQuestion.question || !selectedQuestion.type}"
       class="add" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="new" type="button">New</button>
  </td>
</tr>
{^{for questions}}
  <tr>
    <td>
      {^{:question}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {^{:~typeName(type)}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="editQuestion" type="button">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/for}}
```

The code simplifies down to the following:

```
$('#main').on('click', '.editQuestion', function() {
  $.observable(app).setProperty("selectedQuestion", $.view(this).data);
});

$('#main').on('click', '.add', function() {
  $.observable(question).insert({
    question: newQuestion.question,
    type: newQuestion.type
  });
  $.observable(newQuestion).setProperty({ question: "", type: ""});
});

$('#main').on('click', '.new', function() {
  $.observable(app).setProperty("selectedQuestion", newQuestion);
});
```

Take a look at the following samples which show master-detail editing - so correspond to a related scenario to yours: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/editable

BTW a lot more samples will be on the way soon for MVVM and using view model classes. But in the meantime here is a link which has not yet been exposed publicly on the jsviews.com site: http://www.jsviews.com/#explore/objectsorvm

Comment: Question good Sir, I have doing PHP / JS / HTML / JQuery for years. but this is my first time ealing with MVVM, could you explain to me what makes JSviews better then knockout? Or are they just 2 tools doing the same thing in a different way? I already have part of my the new site using KO (I a rush position), but, depending on the pros / cons, maybe I will switch back :-)

Comment: JsViews is more flexible (e.g. works either with plain javascript objects and arrays, or with mapped MVVM instances using view model classes - does not require specific wrappers, does not require observable fields to be mapped to functions), works with jsrender templates which are much more powerful and flexible than ko native templates (which require wrapping text fields in elements or inserting ko-comments). Features of ko like computed observables, binding events to MVVM methods, etc are all available in JsViews. In JsViews tag binding goes further, e.g both 'if' and 'else' binding.

Comment: KO is more prescriptive (which some may prefer: having less choices). See this blog, from some time back, which did a quick comparison: http://bit.ly/1gIluqU: The con expressed there for JsViews of lacking documentation and samples is no longer true. (The blog was written before www.jsviews.com site existed). The other con of not having declarative event binding is also no longer the case. JsViews is not yet V1.0. (But current code is very robust and stable. Used by Outlook.com and Azure Management Portal, for example). V1.0 is coming soon - along with additional docs.